# Как подсоединиться к репозиторию, созданному ранее на другом компьютере?

Tags: git, ssh-key

На домашнем компе создал репозиторий, настроил ключи т.д. Как мне теперь подключиться к этому репозиторию с рабочего компьютера? Мне каким-то образом нужно ввести ssh ключ? Как это сделать? Через какую команду? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: ОС? ssh сервер уже запущен?

Comment: Windows10. Проект создал на gitlab

Comment: git clone на нужной машине